# Uncaught Error: class 'OTPHP\\TOTP' MAMP (MySQL /w Apache PHP on MacOS X)

Tags: php, mamp

it is my first practice of php(MAMP stack) and I want login 'MFA' feature

I install [otphp](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/otphp)

and follow tutorial in README.md

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>1aefwefawef</h1>
<?php
use OTPHP\TOTP;

$otp = new TOTP;
echo $otp;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

but there's no change in `127.0.0.1:8080/number.php`

so I check the `error.log`

```
Tue Dec 05 18:35:11.950337 2017] [php7:error] [pid 98137] [client 127.0.0.1:60727] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'OTPHP\\TOTP' not found in /Applications/mampstack-7.1.11-0/apache2/htdocs/number.php:12\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /Applications/mampstack-7.1.11-0/apache2/htdocs/number.php on line 12
```

I think it is import error but I can't find where is correct location

In number.php

`/Applications/mampstack-7.1.11-0/apache2/htdocs`

location of otphp

`/Applications/mampstack-7.1.11-0/apache2/htdocs/vendor/spomky-labs/otphp`

location of TOTP.php

`/Applications/mampstack-7.1.11-0/apache2/htdocs/vendor/spomky-labs/otphp/src`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to load your dependencies ?
Take a look at [Autoloading](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.spl-autoload-register.php) or [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) if you have many dependencies...

Hope it helps

Comment: um.... I install otphp using composer already,, any ways thank you about your advice!

Comment: Ok but I don't see in your code where you do require your autoload (in `project_root_dir/vendor/autoload.php`). This might be why it failed to find the dependencie

Comment: oh... sorry about late answer... I'm wake up now,, I'll try about your advice! you means `number.php` needs `autoload_function` did i get your advice right?

Comment: Yep sorry I might not have been quite clear. More info [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) ;)